# Group an object

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, groups

I modeled some vehicles for a map and I still need to do a hitbox. I follow a [tutorial on a website](https://tf2maps.net/threads/tutorial-blender-and-the-source-engine.28408) and there in mentioned:

> "Note that each piece doesn’t have to be a cube, as long as it is
>   convex (not having any interior angles greater than 180°. (picture))
>   and a sealed solid. (...) Note that all parts of the collision mesh
>   must be within the same model."

What do I have to do exactly, if all parts have to be in the same model and it is convex? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> is not working because it then becomes one object.

[image]

If you have any questions just tell me. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick glance at the article would suggest that the hitbox model is supposed to be one object, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> would be the correct way to join them. This will still keep each piece of the hotbox model seperate (they won't be 'fused' together) but will make them into a single object.

Comment: I tried it with that technique and its not working then (Control + J). I heard something about grouping objects. Is there a way to do this? But thank you for the answer :)

Comment: You can group objects with Ctrl-G, but from the article Ctrl-J will be the best way. What's not working for you?

Comment: Grouping only serves as a selection tool, and doesn't enable the group to behave like a single object. The parts are all separate meshes but one object when joined with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>

Comment: The hitbox is not convex when grouping all objects, so the program for the map (hammer) will generat a hitbox for it.

Comment: Have you tried joining the objects with Ctrl J and then following the rest of the tutorial? From everything I read, as long as each section of the hitbox object is convex, then everything should work fine. When two convex objects are joined with Ctrl J, they do not become convex, even if they intersect and the intersection causes the whole object to be convex in places.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the mistake! It was no problem with the model or the group. I just had to smooth the model complete! So I thank everyone who told me that the Control + J technique  should be right :P